How to get csrf token in vue component from laravel using stripe
I have problem with getting redirected correctly to payment method. I'm using laravel 10 as backend and vue3 as frontend. I'm getting error message: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at: (stripe checkout link) (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.Below I show i that in cookies i have xsrf token and also put code:
const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed in getting CSRF:", error);
    }
};

const savePaymentMethod = async () => {
    localStorage.setItem('paymentMethod', paymentForm.value.payment_method);
    
    try {
         await getToken(); 
         await axios.post('/checkout');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error with sending payment:", error);
    }
};

 <form @submit.prevent="savePaymentMethod" method="post">
    <div class="mb-4">
        <label for="payment_method" class="block mb-2">Payment Method:</label>
            <select v-model="paymentForm.payment_method" id="payment_method" required class="border rounded p-2 w-full">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select payment method</option>
                <option value="stripe">Stripe</option>
            </select>
      </div> 
<button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Pay</button>
</form>

In the console displayed link for payment but with errors why does it happens?
I have tried to put the token in the meta tag of header (view)
Like in this example: How to refer laravel csrf field inside a vue template

Well the error is pretty clear. Your server apparently is not setup to allow CORS requests to the external Stripe origin. It seems you are missing a correctly configured Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Before using Sanctum, you must understand the difference between "API Token Authentication" and "SPA Authentication". Please state which one you are using in your question. "SPA Authentication" can only be used on the same origin or within the same domain. If you get a CORS error, you are trying to use "SPA Authentication" without understanding it.
Assuming you are using "SPA Authentication on a subdomain of the same domain".

Laravel: http://laravel.example.com
Vue: http://example.com

What is needed in the question is not the code but the environment you are running it in.
The root cause is a mistake in the CORS settings in config/cors.php. The default for Laravel10 is "only allow api/* and sanctum/csrf-cookie from all domains". The checkout in your question is not allowed.
Therefore, allowing everything should solve the problem. Restrict the front URL.
// config/cors.php 

'paths' => ['*'], 
'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')], 

If you plan to run it on a different domain in production, the code you are writing now will not work at all.

Laravel: http://example-laravel
Vue: http://example-vue

